# Is it possible to include contents of a wiki page in another wiki page?

Tags: github, wiki, github-flavored-markdown

Is it possible with the Github wiki to include the contents of another wiki page in a wiki page?

Answer (score 2):

Not directly.

Yo would need to use a preprocessor in order to include or embed one document in another.
See for instance [`gajus/gitdown`](https://github.com/gajus/gitdown):

> Gitdown adds [additional functionality](https://github.com/gajus/gitdown#features) (generating table of contents, **including documents**, using variables, etc.) to [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/).

In your case: [Include file](https://github.com/gajus/gitdown#include-file).